# Print DataBase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I made the front end of an application but now I have to make the back end and therefore print a DB the problem is that I have an error "Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore" :

App delegate :

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

DataBase :

```
struct New: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var news: String
}

class NewsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var news = [New]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchDate() {
        db.collection("News").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.news = documents.map { (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> New in
                let data = QueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let news = data["News"] as? String ?? "ya r"
                
                return New(news: news)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Print DB :

```
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.news) { news in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(news.news)
                }
                .navigationTitle("News")
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            self.viewModel.fetchDate()
        }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add it inside `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

Comment: or should I add this?

Comment: I tried to put it in place of my appdelagte but I always get the same error